# Fantasy book series where main character makes potion to give him power to turn things to gold but accidentally gives him super speed

Tags: story-identification, books

Read this book series when I was younger (around 10 years ago) but cannot remember what it is called.

In the first book, the young boy tried to make a potion that should give him the ability to turn things into gold. However, he makes a mistake and the potion actually gives him incredible speed.

This same character also appears in the second book but isn’t the main character.

Comment: Hi there! :) Maybe you could add some details upon reading [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028)? Who knows, that might trigger some more memories that you could [edit] into the question to increase your chance of a successful identification. For instance when did you read it? You were younger, sure, but which year/decade was that? Cheers!

Comment: It would have been about 10 years ago maybe. I can’t remember any more details - sorry!

Comment: Alright, every info's good to take :)

Comment: What language did you read the book in? Who was it aimed at (YA, Adult?), how many books were in the series? Was there any sex/nudity/love-interest? What did he do with his super-speed? Why did he want to make gold? What did the potion contain? How long was the book? How old was the protagonist? Was there a villain? What was on the book cover? What was the boy's name? How did he learn that he had superpowers?

Answer (score 2):

*[Whizzard!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whizzard!)* ([*Tales of the Dark Forest*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/66522-tales-of-the-dark-forest) #2) by Steve Barlow and Steve Skidmore.

> Tym, a wizard's apprentice from the Dun Indewood suburb of Leafy Bottom, dreams of being a great magician. It is only when he encounters the mysterious Dreamwalker that he learns the secret of travelling at super-speed and becomes a Whizzard! When his newfound skill causes havoc and puts the beautiful Lady Zamarind into a coma, Tym must travel far across the Dark Forest to save her, and discover his true destiny.